# Decode Quoted-printable strings in Ruby / Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex, encoding

I am using the Ruby mail library https://github.com/mikel/mail/

I am looking for a solution to decode Quoted-printable strings (using this library or natives Ruby function)

My Ruby version is ruby 1.9.2p294

Any solution in Javascript from client side is also good.

Any clue?

Comment: Did you mean to tag this [tag:encoding] instead of [tag:encryption] maybe?

Comment: Example input/output would help

Comment: I use the gmail gem.

When I get emails, sometimes they are in "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable", example: "=EC=95=88=EB=85=95=ED=95=98=EC=84=B8=EC=9A=94!" this is "Hello" in Korean = 안녕하세요

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to decode it by `decodeURIComponent(str.replace(/=/g,'%'))`

***Test code in Javascript:***

```
var input = 'Hello! in Korean is: =EC=95=88=EB=85=95=ED=95=98=EC=84=B8=EC=9A=94!';
var output = decodeURIComponent(input.replace(/=/g,'%'));

document.writeln(output);
```

***Output:***

```
Hello! in Korean is: 안녕하세요!
```

*Try this code online [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DR85X/).*